# TypeError: table is null when adding row to table

Tags: javascript

I am Trying to create and add elements to a table.

```
function flaeche() {
    let tableID = "testTable";
    let x = document.createElement("TABLE");
    x.setAttribute("id", tableID);
    for (let argument of arguments) {
        let radius = ((argument*argument)*Math.PI).toFixed(2);
        addRow(argument,radius,tableID);
    }
}

function addRow(value, result, tableID){
    let table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    let row = table.insertRow(0);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = value;
    cell2.innerHTML = result;
}
```

If I try to run the code I get the following error: 
`TypeError: table is null` at `addRow line 30:5` 
which corresponds to 
`let table = document.getElementById(tableID);`
I really have no idea why it says so since I am fairly new to JavaScript. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Sorry and thanks, I just realized I pasted the same function twice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.getElementById is returning null even after being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416029/document-getelementbyid-is-returning-null-even-after-being-created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a `table` element, but you aren't adding it to the page. You need to actually put the table somewhere in the DOM if you want to find it with `document.getElementById()` later. For example:

```js
function flaeche() {
    let tableID = "testTable";
    let x = document.createElement("TABLE");
    x.setAttribute("id", tableID);

    // add table to the page somewhere
    // for example in the div named container
    let container = document.getElementById("container")
    container.appendChild(x)

    for (let argument of arguments) {
        let radius = ((argument*argument)*Math.PI).toFixed(2);
        addRow(argument,radius,tableID);
    }
}

function addRow(value, result, tableID){
    let table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    let row = table.insertRow(0);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = value;
    cell2.innerHTML = result;
}

flaeche(5, 6)
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: OK interesting it clearly works in stack overflow but if I try to run the code I get the following error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: @Lukee -- I added a container element with id `container` for this example. You need a parent element to attache the table to. Then you can replace the `document.getElementById("container")` with whatever you want to attach the table to.

Comment: I tried your code I even created a new project put still if I run it I get the same error every time. It really makes no sense to me that it works here but not if I create files for it.

Comment: @LukasKönig are you adding a `<div id="container"></div>` to the html like in the example?

Comment: Yes, I added it to the body of the html file. The HTML file is an new with Webstorm autogenerated file the only thing i added was the `<div id="container"></div>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: @LukasKönig you need to make sure scripts that add things to the page load after the page is ready. You can use an onload handler or put the script tag at the bottom right before  `</body>`

Comment: Oh, thanks I didn't know that I had put it in the head as our teacher told us.